# Extract a string from a expression object in R

Tags: r, string

I need to extract a string from a expression object in R. Here is the code:

```
> library(Ryacas)
> x <- Sym("x")
> fun <- expression(1/((exp(-x))+((0.24)+(0.78))))
> my.string <- Simplify.Expr((deriv(fun,x)))
> my.string
```

And a get this output:

```
expression(exp(-x)/(exp(-x)^2 + 2.04 * exp(-x) + 1.0404))
There were 17 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I need to extract only the word "expression" but I've tried several things and nothing works.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: What do you mean you need to "extract only the word expression"? It's important to note that `my.string ` isn't a string. If you do `class(my.string)` you'll see it's an `Expr` object. If you really need that as a string, maybe you want `deparse(yacas(Eval(my.string))[[1]])`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your advice! I've already checked that `my.string` is a `Expr` object. What I want to do is read a .txt file with some expressions and calculate the derivate of that expressions. I thought that `my.string` was indeed a string. I'll test your suggestion. Thanks again!